# How to set a breakpoint in java class dependency in VScode

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have have a Java project under VScode debugger and would like to set a breakpoint to a method which is only available as a compiled `.class` file (from a jar package which came as a dependency in maven project).

Since it is not a `.java` file in my VScode project, I cannot simply open the file from the file browser and set a breakpoint in the file.

How can I set a breakpoint when I only know the method and class by name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following hack worked for me:

1. Create a variable of the class you want to set a breakpoint in.
2. Ctrl-click the class of the variable to get VSCode to open the class's file.
3. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

I had a test, it seems like you can't get this ability in VSCode, but you can get this in Intellij IDEA.